Quarkus - Tenant Resolver
I am using Tenant resolver for implementing multi tenant functionality. I am getting this warning in whenever tenant resolver is called in the code flow.
A bean of type io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.tenant.TenantResolver is being retrieved even though it doesn't have a @PersistenceUnitExtension qualifier. This is deprecated usage and will not work in future versions of Quarkus. Annotate this bean with @PersistenceUnitExtension to make it future-proof.
Any suggestions?
Need to fix this warning in logs

The message cointains the suggestion. Annotate your custom tenant resolver bean with @PersistenceUnitExtension. More info here:  https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multitenancy

May I hazard a guess: annotate this bean with @PersistenceUnitExtension, like the message you quoted is suggesting? :)
If you already did, we'll need a reproducer to help.
